# Issue when combining WHERE statements using AND in SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I'm experiencing an odd error trying to combine multiple statements in my WHERE clause in SQL.

For example, this statement runs fine and does exactly what i would expect:

```
select
abr.[Email Address] as [SubscriberKey],
abr.[date_triggered],
abr.[ProductRatingRef1],
abr.[NumberOfReviewsRef1],
abr.[ProductNameRef1],
abr.[ProductCategoryRef1],
abr.[ProductTypeRef1],
abr.[GBP_RegularPriceRef1],
abr.[SkuIDRef1],
abr.[ProductCodeRef1],
abr.[ProductLinkRef1],
abr.[ImageLinkRef1]

from [Abandon Browse Log] abr

where (abr.[Email Address] not in ( 
  select bkt.CustomerID
  from [Abandoned Basket Source] bkt
))
```

Similarly, this statement runs how i would expect, when i run it on the data extension populated by the above query:

```
select * from [Abandon Browse Campaign v2]

where convert(date, ([date_triggered])) = convert(date, (getdate() -1))
```

Even running this query works fine:

```
select
abr.[Email Address] as [SubscriberKey],
abr.[date_triggered],
abr.[ProductRatingRef1],
abr.[NumberOfReviewsRef1],
abr.[ProductNameRef1],
abr.[ProductCategoryRef1],
abr.[ProductTypeRef1],
abr.[GBP_RegularPriceRef1],
abr.[SkuIDRef1],
abr.[ProductCodeRef1],
abr.[ProductLinkRef1],
abr.[ImageLinkRef1]

from [Abandon Browse Log] abr

where
(convert(date, ([date_triggered])) = convert(date, (getdate() -1)))
```

However, to get around the issue of using 2 queries and 2 (3?) Data Extensions, I am trying to combine both in to one as below:

```
select
abr.[Email Address] as [SubscriberKey],
abr.[date_triggered],
abr.[ProductRatingRef1],
abr.[NumberOfReviewsRef1],
abr.[ProductNameRef1],
abr.[ProductCategoryRef1],
abr.[ProductTypeRef1],
abr.[GBP_RegularPriceRef1],
abr.[SkuIDRef1],
abr.[ProductCodeRef1],
abr.[ProductLinkRef1],
abr.[ImageLinkRef1]

from [Abandon Browse Log] abr

where (abr.[Email Address] not in ( 
  select bkt.CustomerID
  from [Abandoned Basket Source] bkt
))
and 
(convert(date, ([date_triggered])) = convert(date, (getdate() -1)))
```

I would expect this query to work, as both of the above work when separate, but not when combined. The only error i get out of salesforce is :

> The query syntax is invalid Error while parsing query. Please check
>   the syntax

Comment: What is the common field between `[Abandoned Basket Source]` and `[Abandon Browse Log]`?

Comment: Hi Adam, the common field is [Email Address]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `[Email Address]` is the common field between `[Abandoned Basket Source]` and `[Abandon Browse Log]` then you could do something like this:

```
select
  abr.[Email Address] as [SubscriberKey]
, abr.[date_triggered]
, abr.[ProductRatingRef1]
, abr.[NumberOfReviewsRef1]
, abr.[ProductNameRef1]
, abr.[ProductCategoryRef1]
, abr.[ProductTypeRef1]
, abr.[GBP_RegularPriceRef1]
, abr.[SkuIDRef1]
, abr.[ProductCodeRef1]
, abr.[ProductLinkRef1]
, abr.[ImageLinkRef1]
from [Abandon Browse Log] abr
where convert(date, abr.date_triggered) = convert(date, getdate() -1)
and abr.[Email Address] not in ( 
  select bkt.[Email Address]
  from [Abandoned Basket Source] bkt
)
```

or

```
select
  abr.[Email Address] as [SubscriberKey]
, abr.[date_triggered]
, abr.[ProductRatingRef1]
, abr.[NumberOfReviewsRef1]
, abr.[ProductNameRef1]
, abr.[ProductCategoryRef1]
, abr.[ProductTypeRef1]
, abr.[GBP_RegularPriceRef1]
, abr.[SkuIDRef1]
, abr.[ProductCodeRef1]
, abr.[ProductLinkRef1]
, abr.[ImageLinkRef1]
from [Abandon Browse Log] abr
left join [Abandoned Basket Source] bkt on bkt.[Email Address] = abr.[Email Address]
where convert(date, abr.date_triggered) = convert(date, getdate() -1)
and bkt.[Email Address] is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch the position of the conditions in the WHERE clause. I just tested and it worked for me.

```
select
abr.[Email Address] as [SubscriberKey],
abr.[date_triggered],
abr.[ProductRatingRef1],
abr.[NumberOfReviewsRef1],
abr.[ProductNameRef1],
abr.[ProductCategoryRef1],
abr.[ProductTypeRef1],
abr.[GBP_RegularPriceRef1],
abr.[SkuIDRef1],
abr.[ProductCodeRef1],
abr.[ProductLinkRef1],
abr.[ImageLinkRef1]

from [Abandon Browse Log] abr

where (convert(date, ([date_triggered])) = convert(date, (getdate() -1)))

and 

(abr.[Email Address] not in ( 
  select bkt.CustomerID
  from [Abandoned Basket Source] bkt
))
```